# Identify devices like virtio2 and virtio3 in QEmu

Tags: virtual-machine, devices, qemu, interrupt, virtio

I'm running a virtual machine in QEmu.
The following command in the guest VM
`cat /proc/interrupts | egrep 'virtio.*(input|output)'` gives me the following output:

```
 26:          0       3376          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio2-input
 27:          0          1          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio2-output
 29:          0       3368          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio3-input
 30:          0          2          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio3-output
 32:          0       3490          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio4-input
 33:          0          1          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio4-output
 35:          0       4995          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio5-input
 36:          0          1          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio5-output
 38:          0    1818743          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio6-input
 39:          0          1          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio6-output
 41:          0    1822784          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio7-input
 42:          0          1          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio7-output
 44:          0       2470          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio8-input
 45:          0          0          2          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio8-output
 47:          0          0         94          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio9-input
 48:          0          0          1          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio9-output
```

`virtio2`...`virtio9` seem to be 8 network cards. However, I can't figure out which of them corresponds to which card. Is there a way to get MAC address of say `virtio3` , or identify the network card in any other way?

Answer (score 1):

I have a method (taken on another forum few times ago)

```
# vm mac address list
for vm in $(virsh list | grep running | awk '{print $2}'); do \
  echo -n "$vm "; \
  virsh dumpxml $vm| grep -oP "52:54:[\da-f:]+" ; 
done > vm_mac.list

# vm ip list
arp -i virbr0 | grep '52:' | while read addr ; do \
  ip=$(echo $addr | awk '{print $1}'); \
  mac=$(echo $addr | awk '{print $3}'); \
  vm=$(grep "$mac" vm_mac.list | awk '{print $1}'); \
  echo "$vm $ip $mac"; \
done | sort
```

Comment: you don't need `\ ` after `do`.  and you don't need `; \ ` to separate lines in a `do` statement.  in fact, you don't need a `\ ` anywhere you've used it, and the only places that you have used `;` where it's actually needed is immediately before each `do`.

Comment: For my bridges `arp -i` produces something like `arp: in 1 entries no match found.` So the script doesn't work.

Comment: you have to adapt ... at less on device name  of course ...